# Finding error in written function: using data frame column name in a newly written function

Tags: r, function, frequency-analysis

Update: I’m specifically trying to understand what about the function I wrote is in error.

I am using the expss package to run frequency tables across multiple response variables, and will be having to repeat this code across multiple columns. I'm trying to write a function to simplify this process, but running into issues.

This is a very simplified version of the code and data  - but hopefully will help me identify what is going wrong

Example df

```
example <- data.frame(org = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
                      q1 = c("apple", "apple", NA, "apple", "apple", "apple", NA),
                        q2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "banana", "banana", "banana", NA),
                      q3 = c("orange", NA, "orange", "orange", NA, "orange", NA),
                      region = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "2", "2"))
```

The way I am running this data successfully that I want to turn into a function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(expss)

#find frequencies for state
pct_tot <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(example, mrset(q1 %to% q3)))

#find frequencies by region
pct_all <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(example, mrset(q1 %to% q3), region)) %>%
  #combine state and region into same table
  left_join(pct_tot, by = "row_labels")
```

Here is the function I wrote:

```
mr_freq_1 <- function(df, a, b, region) {
  #percent tables
  #tables statewide
  pct_tot <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(a %to% b)))
  #tables by region and combined with statewide
  pct_all <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(a %to% b), 
                                                 region)) %>%
                                     left_join(pct_tot, by = "row_labels")
}
```

I've tried calling this function and get errors in all these ways:

```
mr_freq_1(example, example$q1, example$q3, example$region)

mr_freq_1(example, q1, q3, region)

mr_freq_1(example, "q1", "q3", "region")
```

I rewrote the function after reading more about this, and still am having errors. Here is the rewritten code:

```
mr_freq_2 <- function(df, a, b, region) {
  #percent tables
  #tables statewide
  pct_tot <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(df[[a]] %to% df[[b]])))
  #tables by region and combined with statewide
  pct_all <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(df[[a]] %to% df[[b]]), 
                                                 df[[region]])) %>%
                                     left_join(pct_tot, by = "row_labels")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cross_cpct` uses non-standard evaluation so the usual function arguments don't work here. From my opinion, the simplest way to fix it is to use `eval.parent(substitute({...}))`:

```
mr_freq <- function(df, a, b, region) {
    #percent tables
    eval.parent(substitute({
        #tables statewide
        pct_tot <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(a %to% b)))
        #tables by region and combined with statewide
        pct_all <- as.data.frame(cross_cpct(df, mrset(a %to% b), 
                                            region)) %>%
            left_join(pct_tot, by = "row_labels")
        
        pct_all
    }))
}


mr_freq(example, q1, q3, region)
```